# width of beamercolorbox in background

Tags: beamer, backgrounds

How can I make a `beamercolorbox` in the `background` template take the whole width of the slide? The following doesn't work correctly (but it works for some other templates such as `headline`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{banner}{bg=green}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2cm]{banner}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{AA}
  BB
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\hspace{1cm}` just before the `beamercolorbox`.

Comment: that works (as long as it is not followed by any non-%ed line breaks). Do you want to make it an answer?

Comment: To make it slightly more general, you can also use `\hspace{\beamer@leftmargin}`

Comment: Oh please write up the answer. I forgot to find where that 1cm comes from but since you've found that please make it an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to the margin. Add some extra hspace and it all works (thanks @percusse).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{banner}{bg=green}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
  \hspace{\beamer@leftmargin}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2cm]{banner}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{AA}
  BB
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```